# make image animate and bounce at the same time error - jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to make an image jump when the user presses the right arrow key, although I think I have string together the right code, I get this error when I run it:

> jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function

I have looked around, and have seen suggestions that the error has something to do with the versions of jQuery and jQuery UI not matching up.  I am using jQuery UI 1.12.0-rc.2, and the jQuery version is 1.12.4 from the CDN.

This is my code:

HTML:

```
<head>
<title>Barry bounce</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="canvas">
    <img src="img/characters/BarryBall.png" id="barry" alt="">
  </div>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch(e.which) {
    case 39:
      $("#barry").animate({
        left: '+=350'
      }, ( "bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow" ), { queue: false }); 
});
```

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: You yourself said *"versions not matching up."* what version of jQuery version are you using? Did you try using matching versions of jQuery and jQuery UI?

Comment: @TJ I have edited showing what version of jquery UI i am currently using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you wanted to use a jQuery UI `effect`, instead of using `animate`.  Here's an example of how to bounce `#barry`:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch(e.which) {
    case 39:
      $("#barry").effect("bounce", { times: 5 }, "slow");
      break;
  }
});
```

You can see the whole solution in this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mgaskill/myor8goo/.  This code does a few additional things beyond what was asked, and shows how to use a few different animations on the ball when the arrow keys are pressed.  Use these keys to interact with the ball:

- `up` will bounce the ball in place
- `left` will move the ball left and then bounce it
- `right` will move the ball right and then bounce it
- `down` will shrink the ball temporarily

The issue that you were having with `jQuery.easing` is that the arguments that you were passing to `animate` were simply in the wrong positions.  In fact, both the second and third arguments were improperly placed.  This is the method signature that you were matching: `.animate( properties, duration, easing, complete)`, with `( "bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow" )` applied to `duration`, and `{ queue: false }` used for the `easing` parameter, hence the error on `jQuery.easing`.

Regarding jQuery UI compatibility with jQuery, jQuery UI comes with a mini version of the jQuery core built in for its own use; there's no conflict between versions of jQuery and jQuery UI.

Note that you can also load the jQuery UI from a CDN, so that you don't have to host it yourself.  A side benefit is that it can make your page load significantly faster by loading from a CDN.  Check out the CDN details here: https://code.jquery.com/ui/.  The jQuery UI in the jsFiddle is loaded from here: https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: if you can manage to make the ball bounce at the same time as it moves, I will award it. I have managed to do this my self using an external plugin. So I am working on my own answer. If you manage this please link the fiddle!!

Comment: @seus I did manage to make the ball bounce and move at the same time.  I actually had that working earlier, but since your question didn't actually say that was what you wanted, I removed it from the sample.  I've updated the same jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mgaskill/myor8goo/ to include the bouncing while it moves left and right.  I believe that's what you wanted.

Comment: @seus Glad to have helped.  Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

`bounce` isn't a valid [jQuery UI easing](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/), it is instead used with [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), being a CSS animation rather than a jQuery animation. In addition, you missing the necessary CSS include. I've produced a (sort of) [working sample on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ouroborus/bt3th3wy/), quoted here:

```html
<div id="canvas">
  <img src="http://kilon.org/samples/images/ball.png" id="barry" alt="" style="position:relative;">
</div>
```

```js
$('body').on('keydown',function(e) {
  switch(e.keyCode) {
    case 39:
      $( "#barry" ).toggle( "bounce", { times: 1 }, "slow" );
  }
});
```

Comment: please see https://api.jqueryui.com/bounce-effect/ , this is what im trying to play around with

Comment: Updated answer and links.

Comment: so is there anyway to achieve a moving bounce effect using jquery ui?

Comment: The equivalent in jQuery UI is `easeInBounce` and friends. Use the proper [animate syntax](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). jQuery and jQuery UI don't have a preset "bounce and return" kind of animation, just a bounce out and bounce in.